# JavaFX StackedBarChart - clearing series leaves invisible data in the chart

Tags: java, javafx, charts, javafx-8

The StackedBarChart shows strange behaviour, when the data of a series is cleared. I want to use a StackedBarChart where I can switch between multiple homogenous datasets i.e. each dataset has one numerical value (yAxis) for each month of a year (xAxis).

This minimal example shows the problem pretty well:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MinStackedBarChartProblem extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        StackedBarChart<String, Number> root = new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        root.getData().add(series);
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("test", 1.0d));
        series.getData().clear();
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("test", 1.0d));
        show(primaryStage, root);
    }

    private void show(Stage primaryStage, Parent root) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I construct a chart with a single series and put one data entry in with the value 1.
Then I clear that series and add 1 again.
The resulting bar starts at 1 and ends at 2 while the range [0..1] is empty.

I can work around this by creating new series objects which in turn change their colors which I have another workaround for.

But does anyone know how to fix this? Am I doing something wrong?
Should I file this as a bug?

---

P.S.:
Looked at the source. The problem seems to be

```
private Map<Series, Map<String, List<Data<X, Y>>>> seriesCategoryMap
```

a member of StackedBarChart. StackedBarChart does not bother to remove values from there.

---

Someone proposed a [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052685/recreate-bar-chart-without-it-remembering-data) which is somewhat different.
First of all the solution to that problem does not solve this problem.
Also in that case only the order of the data is wrong,
but the data looks correct.

[A stacked bar chart NOT starting at 0 makes no sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrBcJ.png)

The first data-object is still used by said categoryMap to calculate the offset from the x-axis though it is not drawn.

This is just for documentation of that unexpected behaviour though,
I already switched to the workaround.

Comment: It does not make a difference if the chart is animated or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recreate bar chart without it remembering data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052685/recreate-bar-chart-without-it-remembering-data)

Comment: seems to be fixed in fx10

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around.  Before you do the clear.  Set the Y value to 0.

```
series.getData().forEach(a -> a.setYValue(0));
```